# How to influnce a python generator while using it without using globals: time example

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

I try to influence a generator at runtime. The code works using a global, I am asking for a *more pythonic way* to achive the same result.

This example prints out hour and minute for a time range. The range from 13:15 to 15:45 should be skipped (this is an example, in the real world the decision to skip some values is not fixed)

Can I pass the *globalskiptime* to the generator some better way?

```
import datetime

globalskiptime = None


def mynexttime(mystart=None):
    # returns 15 30 45 59 minute for each hour
    for myhour in range(0, 24):
        for myminute in range(15, 61, 15):
            if mystart is not None:
                if datetime.time(myhour, myminute
                                 if myminute < 60 else 59) < mystart:
                    continue
            if globalskiptime is not None:
                if datetime.time(myhour, myminute
                                 if myminute < 60 else 59) < globalskiptime:
                    continue
            yield myhour, myminute if myminute < 60 else 59


mystarttime = datetime.time(10, 45)

print type(mystarttime) is datetime.time

for h, m in mynexttime(mystarttime):
    print(str(h) + " " + str(m))
    if h == 13:
        print('skip until 15:45')
        globalskiptime = datetime.time(15, 45)
```

Comment: This section of the documentation might help you: [Passing values into a generator](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#passing-values-into-a-generator)

Comment: @VincentSavard - the `.send()` method seems to do what I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @VincentSavard hint I rewrote the code to use `send()` to send data into the generator. I had to give up the for-loop at the end, but changing a for-loop during runtime is hacky anyway.

This is what I settled for:

```
import datetime

def mynexttime(mystart=None):
    # returns 15 30 45 59 minute for each hour
    for myhour in range(0, 24):
        for myminute in range(15, 61, 15):
            if mystart is not None:
                if datetime.time(myhour, myminute
                                 if myminute < 60 else 59) < mystart:
                    continue
            mystart = (yield myhour, myminute if myminute < 60 else 59)

# start at 12:45
mytest = mynexttime(datetime.time(12, 45))

breaktime = None
while True:
    try:
        h, m = mytest.send(breaktime)
        print(str(h) + ":" + str(m))
        if h == 13:
            breaktime = datetime.time(15, 44)
            print('skip until 15:45')
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a state variable which isn't a primitive type:

```
def gen(cur):
    for ii in range(0, 10):
        yield ii + cur[0]

state = [100]
for num in gen(state):
    print num
    state[0] += 100
```

It outputs:

```
100
201
302
403
504
605
706
807
908
1009
```

Comment: Thanks, that's better then using a global (and will do for what I'm trying to achive). It still feels a bit hacky to me, so I'll wait if there are some other ideas before marking this solved.

Comment: I suppose you could encapsulate it in a class (making the generator a method instead of a free function).